# How to create tables using GoogleAppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to store a list of friends and their locations (GPS coordinates) on the googleAppengine.  I am using J2ME with Netbeans. How do I store or create table in Google App Engine?

Comment: Well swati. I recommend you to use Eclipse for GAE Development.

Answer (score 2):

The App Engine datastore is schemaless. The closest thing to a table in a relational database is the *kind*. Each *kind* holds *entities* (records) all of which have *attributes* (fields). It is important to note that the *entities* of a given *kind* do not need to have the same *attributes*. See the [datastore documentatio](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Entities)n for more information.

When writing to the App Engine datastore you do not create a table / kind in advance, instead you simply create the entity (record) of a given kind you'd like to store, and tell App Engine to store it. See [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Kinds_and_Identifiers) for a short example.

If you would like to use a relational database with App Engine, use Google Cloud SQL (essentially a MySQL database co-located with your App Engine application).

Comment: For Google Cloud SQL, you have to pay extra. For the datastore, you can use JDO or JPA abstractions if you know those from relational database development.

Comment: as i am very use to netbeans.. i dont have much idea about eclipse..can i do the same in netbeans?